# Find a cumulative sum of one column between instances of value in second column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this;

```
df <- data.frame(Trip =c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)), 
                 State =c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 Distance = c(0,2,9,4,3,1,4,5,6,3,2,6,1,5,3,3,6,1,8,2), 
                 DistanceToNext = c(NA,NA,NA,3,1,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,17,NA,NA,NA,1,8,NA,NA)) 

   Trip State Distance DistanceToNext
1  A 0 1  NA
2  A 0 2  NA
3  A 0 9  NA
4  A 1 4   3
5  A 1 3   1
6  A 1 1  15
7  A 0 4  NA
8  A 0 5  NA
9  A 1 6  NA
10 A 0 3  NA
11 B 0 2  NA
12 B 1 6   1
13 B 1 1  17
14 B 0 5  NA
15 B 0 3  NA
16 B 0 3  NA
17 B 1 6   1
18 B 1 1   8
19 B 1 8  NA
20 B 0 2  NA
```

The State column indicates whether a fishing boat is fishing (State = 1) or not fishing (State = 0). I want to calculate the Distance travelled between each fishing event (State = 1).

The Distance column indicates the distance between that rows location and the previous row (e.g. it is the lag distance).

The DistanceToNext column is the answer I am trying to generate, it should be `NA` for all rows in the Trip until the first row where the fishing State = 1. For this row DistanceToNext should equal the sum of the Distance column of subsequent rows until the next fishing State = 1.

For example row 4 is the first fishing event (State = 1) in Trip A, the DistanceToNext cell should be the Distance travelled before the next fishing event which in his case is the very next row (row 5) which has a distance of 3.

For row 5 the next fishing event is again the very next row (row 6) which has a distance of 1. However for row 6 we see that there isn't another fishing event until row 9 so I want a cumulative sum of the d column for the rows between 6 and 9 which is 15.

If it is the last State = 1 row in it's x grouping (A or B) then there isn't another fishing event so there is not distance to calculate so I want it to give `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution you could use. I also used a custom function for every `State`/ `Distance` vectors in each group that results in the desired output:

```
fn <- function(State, Distance) {
  out <- rep(NA, length(State))
  
  inds <- which(State == 1)
  for(i in inds) {
    if(State[i] == 1 & State[i + 1] == 1) {
      out[i] <- Distance[i + 1]
    } else if (State[i] == 1 & State[i + 1] == 0 & i != inds[length(inds)]) {
      nx <- which(inds == i)
      out[i] <- sum(Distance[(i+1):(inds[nx + 1])])
    } else {
      NA
    }
  }
  out
}

df %>%
  group_by(Trip) %>%
  mutate(MyDistance = fn(State, Distance))

# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   Trip [2]
   Trip  State Distance DistanceToNext MyDistance
   <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A         0        0             NA         NA
 2 A         0        2             NA         NA
 3 A         0        9             NA         NA
 4 A         1        4              3          3
 5 A         1        3              1          1
 6 A         1        1             15         15
 7 A         0        4             NA         NA
 8 A         0        5             NA         NA
 9 A         1        6             NA         NA
10 A         0        3             NA         NA
11 B         0        2             NA         NA
12 B         1        6              1          1
13 B         1        1             17         17
14 B         0        5             NA         NA
15 B         0        3             NA         NA
16 B         0        3             NA         NA
17 B         1        6              1          1
18 B         1        1              8          8
19 B         1        8             NA         NA
20 B         0        2             NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you would do:

```
fun <- function(df){
    a <- which(df$State == 1)
    b <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
    d <- mapply(function(x, y) sum(df$Distance[(x+1):y]), head(a,-1), tail(a, -1))
    b[a] <- c(d, NA)
    transform(df, DisttoNext = b)
}

do.call(rbind, by(df, df$Trip, fun))
     Trip State Distance DistanceToNext DisttoNext
A.1     A     0        0             NA         NA
A.2     A     0        2             NA         NA
A.3     A     0        9             NA         NA
A.4     A     1        4              3          3
A.5     A     1        3              1          1
A.6     A     1        1             15         15
A.7     A     0        4             NA         NA
A.8     A     0        5             NA         NA
A.9     A     1        6             NA         NA
A.10    A     0        3             NA         NA
B.11    B     0        2             NA         NA
B.12    B     1        6              1          1
B.13    B     1        1             17         17
B.14    B     0        5             NA         NA
B.15    B     0        3             NA         NA
B.16    B     0        3             NA         NA
B.17    B     1        6              1          1
B.18    B     1        1              8          8
B.19    B     1        8             NA         NA
B.20    B     0        2             NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` alternative.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,`:=`(next_dist = shift(Distance, type = "lead"), g = cumsum(State), ri = .I),
   by = Trip]     
d = df[ , .(ri = ri[1], State = State[1], s = sum(next_dist)), by = .(Trip, g)]
df[d[State == 1, .SD[-.N], by = Trip], on = .(ri), s := s]
df[ , `:=`(ri = NULL, next_dist = NULL, g = NULL)]

#     Trip State Distance DistanceToNext  s
#  1:    A     0        0             NA NA
#  2:    A     0        2             NA NA
#  3:    A     0        9             NA NA
#  4:    A     1        4              3  3
#  5:    A     1        3              1  1
#  6:    A     1        1             15 15
#  7:    A     0        4             NA NA
#  8:    A     0        5             NA NA
#  9:    A     1        6             NA NA
# 10:    A     0        3             NA NA
# 11:    B     0        2             NA NA
# 12:    B     1        6              1  1
# 13:    B     1        1             17 17
# 14:    B     0        5             NA NA
# 15:    B     0        3             NA NA
# 16:    B     0        3             NA NA
# 17:    B     1        6              1  1
# 18:    B     1        1              8  8
# 19:    B     1        8             NA NA
# 20:    B     0        2             NA NA
```

Explanation:

Convert data to `data.table` (`setDT(df)`).

For each 'Trip' (`by = Trip`), create new variables by reference (`:=`): next distance (`shift(Distance, type = "lead")`), a grouping variable which increases everytime 'State' is 1 (`cumsum(State)`), a row index used to join result (`.I`; this also could be done first, without the grouping).

For each 'Trip' and 'State group' (`by = .(Trip, g)`), select first row index (`ri[1]`), first 'State' (`State = State[1]`), and sum the lead distances (`sum(next_dist)`).

From the result above, select rows where 'State' is 1 (`State == 1`). Then, for each 'Trip' (`by = Trip`), select the subset of data (`.SD`) except the last row (`-.N`). Join to the original data on row index (`on = .(ri)`). Create a new column, sum of distances, 's' by reference (`:=`). If desired, remove temp variables.